# Find similar times in 2 variables

Tags: sql

My data set looks like below. What I want to find is the first time that ContactedAt happened after LookedAt. So Pol1 would be row 1 and Pol2 would be row 4.

```
Policy |LookedAt            |ContactedAt          |StoreRef
Pol1   |01/02/20 15:12:45   |01/02/20  16:42:23   |LND 
Pol1   |01/02/20 15:12:45  | 01/02/20  17:15:59  | LND
Pol1   |01/02/20 15:12:45   |29/01/20  10:18:22   |LND
Pol2  | 02/11/20 18:22:15   |02/11/20  20:45:12   |EDI
Pol2   |02/11/20 18:22:15   |03/11/20  11:17:00   |EDI
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by policy order by looked_at) as seqnum
      from t
      where ContactedAt > LookedAt
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This interprets "first" as being the earliest `looked_at` datetime.